# Lilypond score with reverse symbols

Tags: lilypond

I am trying for weeks to to create a line with reverse symbols in Lilypond:[image: Bar of music with the time signature, key, and clef repeated at the end except each of them has been flipped horizontally.]

I know it is possible because i found it in a Lilypond generated pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simpler is...

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "english.ly"
\bookpart { 
\header {
    composer="J.S.Bach"
    opus = "BWV 1087"}

\markup \large "1. Canon simplex"
\score {
\relative c' { 
    \key g \major
    \clef bass
    \time 2/4 
    r4 \repeat volta 2  { 
      g fs e d b c d g,4 }
      \override TextScript #'extra-offset = #'(20 . 5.84)
      s64-\markup{
        \scale #'(-1 . 1) 
        \score {\relative { 
          \key g \major\clef bass\time 2/4 \global r4  }
        }
      } 
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it... is however a lot of hand-adjustments...

```
\version "2.18.2"

\bookpart { 
\header {
composer="J.S.Bach"
opus = "BWV 1087"}
\markup \large "1. Canon simplex"
\score {
\relative c' { 
\key g \major
\clef bass
\time 2/4
r4 \repeat volta 2  { g fis e d b c d g, }
    s8
\override Staff.BarLine #'stencil = ##f 
% gespiegelt
s4
\override TextScript #'extra-offset = #'(-3 . 5.2)
s2-\markup{ %\hspace #10
  \column{ % pause
    \line{
      \scale #'(-1 . 1){
        \lower #1.5 \halign #0 \musicglyph #"rests.2"
      }
  }} \hspace #1
  \column{ %clef
    \line {
      \scale #'(-1 . 1){
        \center-column{
          \lower #1.3 \musicglyph #"two" \musicglyph #"four"
        }
      }
  }}
  \column{ %clef
    \line {
      \scale #'(-1 . 1){
      \musicglyph #"accidentals.sharp"
      }
  }}
  \column{ %clef
    \line {
      \scale #'(-1 . 1){
      \lower #0.2 \musicglyph #"clefs.F"
      }
  }}
}}}}
```

[image: j.s. bach BWV 1087]